# Using usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground() to get the time every application in a device spent in foreground

Tags: android, package, usage-statistics

I want to know the time spent by all applications running in an android device . I am getting all packages names using the following code .Please guide me how to link packages and the above method to get time spent by applications

Here is the code

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (PackageInfo pack : packs) {
        if (pack.firstInstallTime != pack.lastUpdateTime) {
            Log.i("n-names",
                    pack.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                            .toString());
            Log.i("n-install time", pack.firstInstallTime + "");
            Log.i("n-uptime", pack.lastUpdateTime + "");
            UsageStats usage = null;
            usage.getTotalTimeInForeground();
        }
    }
```

Please tell me how to use the above methods for indivudual packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get the foreground running time of all applications in android lollipop use the following piece of code.

//Variables with dummy values and objects.

```
UsageStats usageStats;

String PackageName = "Nothing" ;

long TimeInforground = 500 ;

int minutes=500,seconds=500,hours=500 ;
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats");     

long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*10, time); 

 if(stats != null) 
  {
            SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) 
               {

                TimeInforground=usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground();

                PackageName=usageStats.getPackageName();

                minutes = (int) ((TimeInforground / (1000*60)) % 60);

                seconds = (int) (TimeInforground / 1000) % 60 ;

                hours   = (int) ((TimeInforground / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

                Log.i("BAC", "PackageName is"+PackageName +"Time is: "+hours+"h"+":"+minutes+"m"+seconds+"s");

            }
```

Make sure you have all right permissions in manifest file and app have access with usage under security in settings.

Comment: but how to use this in below (lollipop )5.0 devices.please tell me.

Comment: is this have the ability to tell the whole screen time of the user spent on that android device?