# Regarding finding out time spent on each application in Android KK

Tags: android

Kindly help to figure out a way so that I can find time spent on each application package in Android KK device .

In Android 5.0+ version we have Usage Stats api to get the stats related to app packages in the system.

reference to Android 5.0 : [Using usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground() to get the time every application in a device spent in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563401/using-usagestats-gettotaltimeinforeground-to-get-the-time-every-application-in)

How to get relevant data for package in Android KitKat.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please tell me if you were find any solution.